# How to remove background from a complex figure?

Tags: inkscape, clipping-mask, bezier-curve

**I want to remove the background from this cartoon image :-**

.

[image: cartoon]

I have made outline with the bezier tool.
But when i am filling the color in it, it is not filling the whole image.:-
[image: color filling]

and that's why when i am doing the clipping it is not doing to the whole of the image.

Thank you.

Comment: If this is a raster image, Inkscape may not be the proper tool to use. In addition for an **animation** you would need to edit *every frame*.

Comment: Sorry, this is only a image. i have edited the question.

Comment: Can you share the .svg file? My suspicion would be that the path might not be closed or has loops in it

Comment: .svg can not be uploaded.

Answer (score 1):

Ouch... If it is an animation change the program you are using. Use a video edition tool.

One free and really powerful is Davinci Resolve, where you can choose a range of colors. See if that works.

If it does not work for some parts of the image, you need to do a rotoscoping, which is masking frame by frame as you are currently doing now.

Another free program is HitFilm express.